# Can't get Authcache to work with Memcache as backend: Cache Status: "MISS"

Tags: 7, caching

I have tried to set up Authcache with Memcached as backend. But when I use the debug feature I always get Cache status: "MISS". Am I supposed to use the "built in cache backend" allthough I am using Memcached?

My settings.php file:

```
$conf['memcache_servers']  = array('localhost:11211' => 'default');

$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/memcache/memcache.inc';
$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/authcache/authcache.cache.inc';
$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/authcache/modules/authcache_builtin/authcache_builtin.cache.inc';
$conf['cache_class_cache_page'] = 'MemCacheDrupal';
$conf['cache_class_cache_authcache_key'] = 'MemCacheDrupal';
$conf['cache_class_cache_bootstrap'] = 'MemCacheDrupal';


  // The 'cache_form' bin must be assigned to non-volatile storage.
  $conf['cache_class_cache_form'] = 'DrupalDatabaseCache';
  $conf['memcache_key_prefix'] = 'test';

  // shared settings
  $conf['authcache_builtin_cache_without_database'] = TRUE;
  $conf['page_compression'] = 1;
  $conf['page_cache_maximum_age'] = 600;
```

I have configured AuthCache to cache pages for Guests and logged in users. As far as I can see everything is set up correctly by the book, but I still get these messages. I am obviously missing somehting, so please take a look at this. Does it look correct?

The Authcache debug message:

> Authcache Debug Status 
>   Cache Status: "MISS"
>   Page Render Time: "800.09ms"
>   Page Age: "2 seconds"
>   Settings Cache 
>   Class: "MemCacheDrupal"
>   Cache CID: "http://test.mysite.se/produkter/handinstrument/temperatur" 
>   Debug Users: ["Tommy"]
>   Cache User: 0
>   Cache Backends:"authcache_builtin" 
>   Active Backend: "authcache_builtin"
>   Authcache Key: "http://test.mysite.se"
>   P13n Clients: "Ajax"
>   Active P13n Clients: "Ajax"
>   HTML/JavaScript time: 38 ms

In my status report i get no error messages. This is what i get for Authcache and Memcache:

> Authcache hook_authcache_backend_cache_save() implemented:
>   authcache_builtin
>
> Authcache builtin cache backend  Using MemCacheDrupal as cache backend
>
> Memcache  2.2.0 (mer information)

UPDATE: After hours of trying to find the error, I threw Memcache out and installed File Cache. Which worked like a charm. Pages are displayed incredibly fast, once they are cached. So never mind my question. I will go with the Autchache and File Cache combination.